# Suggest other site for other human languages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, languages

I have searched multiple terms and haven't found this answer.  If a user enters question text on a site dedicated to a specific human written/spoken language, let's say https://stackoverflow.com/ which is English, and the text is some other language, why not attempt to detect the language, via Google translate API or some other API and at least suggest the appropriate site if it exists?

Comment: Why not using a custom close flag, with a comment mentioning the appropriate site? From my experience it's a rather rare case, and often the questions per se, are pretty low quality anyways. I won't support that wasting SO dev time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Yeah, so much more efficient and helpful than alerting the user that there is a site with users of the same language that can help them.

Comment: And what? These questions need to be closed and deleted from SO anyways :-P

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Why?  If it is a well crafted question with concise code and problem description that can help others but is posted on the English site in Spanish, why closed and deleted?

Comment: Because those APIs can (and do) get it wrong. More than one language can use the same alphabet, and even some of the same words and grammars. Human language is messy and best left to humans to work out. We also only have, what, five language-specific SO sites? Certainly that's within our abilities to handle. Also, we can't tell if an English question is "good" automatically; how are we going to do it Russian?

Comment: @AbraCadaver So you're asking for automatic migration?

Comment: No I'm talking about a **suggestion**  _"Hey this is an English language site but you seem to be asking in Spanish, have you considered https://es.stackoverflow.com/"?  You may get more answers there."_

Comment: @HereticMonkey  Yes I know this, however if it is a half-way decent question with several sentences of text it can at least be detected.  Or not detected, and things continue as they are.  I didn't state anything about detecting if it was _"good"_, but I don't understand Spanish so maybe it is good to another Spanish speaker.

Comment: I'm certainly not suggesting that anyone write code in an attempt to automate or streamline anything or make it easier.  That would just be crazy talk.

Comment: "I didn't state anything about detecting if it was "good"," I know you didn't say that but I think it would make an interesting question and they tried it already way back in 2013 I think. It would be interesting to see how that would go nowadays. Most probably better.

Comment: I think this idea is valid.
Not only that, but I hate that in SOpt-br, there is always at least one Brazilian putting an English question, even if it's well-formed, they get completely destroyed by downvotes.

Answer (score 12):

Language detection is *extremely* error-prone, *especially* on a site where people frequently post source code and other non-English text. I don't think this is something that we can do with any reasonable degree of accuracy. Moreover, I don't think it is important. It should be patently obvious to everyone who arrives that this site is entirely in English. If someone can't clue into that basic observation, it's unlikely they'll bother to read some suggestion or hint about another site. Finally, there are only a small number of localized Stack Overflow sites. We don't have truly broad enough coverage of non-English languages for a generalized system like this to work.

Frankly, we would prefer that users not make these types of recommendations manually in comments, either. Even if you can clearly tell that a question is written in, say, Spanish, we would prefer that you not leave a comment suggesting the asker to go visit Spanish.SO. Unless you can actually read Spanish with some degree of fluency, you aren't qualified to assess the quality of the question—and if you can't assess the quality of a question, you aren't able to complete "step 0" of the migration process. Other sites don't want us dumping our unwanted garbage on their lawn. Folks who can't figure out that Stack Overflow is an English-only site are not likely to have much overlap with the folks who produce high-quality content.

Comment: "Language detection is extremely error-prone.." I don't know. Whenever I type something into Google translate it automatically detects the language and so far has been quite good. There is a difference between informing of the existence of another stack exchange and exporting garbage. Also equaling confusion of the right site with low quality might be just too much. I think this answer is a bit too pessimistic overall. I would rather argue that the potential benefit is small compared to the effort of creating and maintaining the feature

Comment: @Trilarion "*Whenever I type something into Google translate it automatically detects the language and so far has been quite good.*" depends on what you type. If it's long and well formatted text e.g., excerpt from a book, then it's generally OK. But if you use some shorter more "free form text" that is not fully grammatically correct or might have some unorthodox spelling, then it's sketchy.  Google translate seems to often think one Slavic language for another, for example. I suspect a lot of the non-English content will also be problematic for detection.

Comment: I almost never have good results with Google Translate's automatic language detection. There are two main types of text that I try to translate: snippets from spam posts here on SO, and snippets from closed captions in shows that I watch that have brief dialogues in languages that I don't speak. So, yes, I think @VLAZ is probably correct about the accuracy being correlated with the length of the text that one attempts to translate. In my experience, I *really* don't think that there is any doubt about the correlation between quality and asking a question on a blatantly wrong site.

Comment: @VLAZ The only languages I speak are quite popular ones with at least 50 million speakers. For them the automatic detection is probably better, so it might have skewed my observation. Just now I tried four non-English languages (French, German, Spanish, Russian) and simple sentences with small spelling errors (exchanged letters and added a few additional letters). Detection was right after 2-3 words on average.

Comment: *"It should be patently obvious to everyone who arrives that this site is entirely in English."* I think this is probably the most telling point. When you sign up, everything you read is in English. You're urged to take the [tour] and vist the [help] to understand the site. If someone hasn't taken the "time" to *infer* that a site completely written in English, with no option to change the viewed language, expects English content to be posted, then it is my opinion that it is *very* unlikely they have researched the problem themselves or the question is of good quality.

Comment: _"Frankly, we would prefer that users not make these types of recommendations manually in comments, either."_ As someone that has an established snippet for directing people to [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) and [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), but isn't fluent in either language, this is really useful to know. I'll be sure to retire that snippet.